# Does classification of a problem also require the algorithm used?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, p-vs-np

Just learnt that a problem in computer science can be divided into the following categories

```
Polynomial problems
NP problems
NP hard problems
NP complete problems
```

based on how long it takes to run the program

For example, suppose there is a problem P that can be solved with two algorithms say A1 and A2 where,

```
A1 is polynomial in nature,
A2 is non-polynomial
```

According to me, if P is solved using A1, then P is a polynomial problem and if P is solved using A2, then it must be an NP problem.

Am I right?

In other words, is it fair enough to say that classification of a problem does also require the algorithm that is being used to solve it?

Comment: possible dup of http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9556/755

Comment: *Definitely* a duplicate (cc @D.W.). Your question is answered by the definitions of the terms you use (without, apparently, really understanding what they mean). The [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9556/755) has wonderful answers that help you gain this understanding.

Answer (score 1):

No. The classification of problems into complexity classes is based on the amount of resources *required* to solve the problem, not the resources that some programmer decides to use. If you have a smart algorithm that solves a problem in polynomial time, and a dumb one that uses exponential time, the problem itself is in polynomial time because it *can* be solved within that resource bound.